# YouTube API returning apostrophe html code

Tags: html, reactjs, youtube-api

I have 2 applications that call the YouTube search API for video results.

Until recently, they returned video titles containing apostrophes, but I opened my apps today and find that videos with apostrophes in the title are returned by the YouTube API with "& # 3 9 ;" *(with no spaces, formatted to stop chrome from just writing an apostrophe)* in place of the apostrophe.

What is also weird is that some videos will properly insert the apostrophe into the title while others don't. I went to search the same query on YouTube itself and it returns no weird results.

Anyone know why this could be happening?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: how are you setting the text? `&#39;` is just an apostrophe html encoded.

Comment: I insert into an object and reference its video title in the HTML code. I tried the same GET request using postman and still get the HTML code

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Iraf2Sh

Comment: Does this only happen for apostrophe? Or have you not tried for other symbols yet?

Comment: I've noticed it happening for quotes, which prints "q u o t ;". I'm not seeing any others though.

Comment: Any updates on this?